# Is it safe when store encrypted credentials in source code

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, bcrypt

I use the Encryptors of Spring framework to cover my S3 credentials and pass decrypt password when start app to decrypt it.

But not sure if it is safe to push to public git repository

Is there another better way to keep it secure?

```
s3:
  endpoint: http://localhost:4566
  key: 5a79278dca41d8fd82cef12c224ab07227cf90ee0251622eb9f3e134d383ba4c
  secret: 5a79278dca41d8fd82cef12c224ab07227cf90ee0251622eb9f3e134d383ba4c
  bucket: pdminhdev
```

Comment: Learn about [_externalized configuration_](https://12factor.net/config). Spring Boot makes this easy with several ways to provide properties at runtime; environment variables and Spring Cloud Config providers are two common options.

Comment: Thank you @chrylis, combine of runtime properties and external config seem fit for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're designing the authentication system as a whole, you shouldn't store passwords, even if they're encrypted. You store a hash, and check if passwords provided during login match the same hash. That way, a security breach on your database avoids getting your users' passwords exposed.

Comment: thank you @Ilan56, I just want to store AWS S3 credential :D